# how to roll pandas datetime 5 minute into the previous business day

Tags: python, timedelta

consider following pandas dataframe df:

```
datestimes,price 
2016-10-28 23:55:00,100.0
2016-10-31 00:00:00,122.4
```

after roll the time back by 5 minute:

```
df.datestimes - pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
```

output:

```
datestimes,price
2016-10-28 23:50:00,100.0
2016-10-30 23:55:00,122.4
```

2016-10-30 is not a business day and 2016-10-28 is, how do i move it to 2016-10-28 23:55:00 as the following?

```
datestimes,price
2016-10-28 23:50:00,100.0
2016-10-28 23:55:00,122.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the typical answer is to go one business day in the past + 1 day in the future:

```
df.datestimes  +pd.datetools.Day(1) - pd.datetools.BDay(1)
```

Comment: Don't you mean the other way round?  The code makes sense but the description appears to say the opposite.

Comment: shoud be : "the typical answer is to go one business day in the past + 1  day in the future. :) thank you!